# Logged user is always sitecore\Anonymous during processor in SC 9.1

Tags: configuration, site-configuration, login

I'm using Sitecore 9.1, thus an identity provider.

I have a **custom domain** named `aba` and I'm logged in Sitecore Administration Console using an `aba\hsantos` user.

Then I have this **processor** which is running on a **custom site definition** called `coveoapi`.

```
<site name="coveoapi" virtualFolder="/coveo" physicalFolder="/coveo" enableTracking="false" content="master" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/identity/login/shell/SitecoreIdentityServer"/>
```

During its execution, the `Sitecore.Context.Domain` is always `sitecore` no matter who is logged in.

Not only that, but the current user is always `sitecore\Anonymous`.

[image]

I suspect that my identity provider is not resolving correctly users from `aba` domain when the current site is `coveoapi`.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: `Sitecore.Context.Domain` is your site context domain, as specified in the very config you post a snippet of. `Sitecore.Context.User.Domain` should be what you're looking for.   Also, be aware of which sites you authenticate to - which may or not be the same as the one you list here.

Comment: Right there in your config you have the `domain` for that site set to sitecore: `domain="sitecore"`. If you are logging into a different site in the site definitions, you will be anonymous in the `coveoapi` site.

Comment: @MarkCassidy thanks Mark. One thing that's weird is that I never authenticate to `coveoapi` and still when I access the instance using the instance name instead of a hostName (aka the site is resolved to `website`) the same test gives my the logged user `aba\hsantos`. That only leads me to think that I must authenticate on the resolved site for the current page, not really the site for the processor. Does that make sense?

Comment: Btw all I said is true even if the logged user is `sitecore\admin`, so we can remove the domain from the possible causes. I'm tending towards something related to *Identity provider can't resolve the current user for a given hostName*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally just like pointed by Mark in comments, **I was only logged in the [instance-name]/ context**.

In order to be able to log in other websites, I had to edit the `config/production/Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml` `<AllowedCorsOrigins>` config in Identity Server instance and add the other website hostnames.

Now I can go to `aba.local/sitecore` and log in, and by doing that, my processor has `aba\hsantos` in `Sitecore.Context.User`.